# How can I check debug mode on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to see errors when I work in the localhost.

App\Exceptions\handler.php

I Tried:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception) && env('APP_DEBUG') === false) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

or;

```
if ($this->isHttpException($exception) && App::environment('APP_DEBUG') === false)
```

I tried it as above but it does not work.

Thanks.

---

APP_DEBUG is set to true in .env

Comment: Did you set APP_DEBUG to true in your .env file?  Always read the manual first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#configuration

Comment: There shouldn't be anything else you need to configure so provide more info.  Are you only seeing the Whoops message and no detail?  Have you tried evaluating `env('APP_DEBUG')` to make sure your .env is loaded properly?

Comment: I'm sure, I set `APP_DEBUG=true` in .env file. I no see any whoops message. 404.blade.php rendered.

Comment: That's not what I asked, I asked if you tried to evaluate it.

Comment: Print out `env('APP_DEBUG')`

Comment: Its returned **1**.

Comment: Ok, a HttpNotFoundException should be skipped by the first block, so something else is going on.  Try just `return parent::render($request, $exception);` at the top of that code.  If you're still getting a 404, then you're probably not dealing with an HttpNotFoundException or your exception handler isn't being used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel how to read app/config/app.php debug variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189725/laravel-how-to-read-app-config-app-php-debug-variable)

Answer (score 54):

To avoid big problems with cache, the right way to check is:

`config('app.debug') == false`

Answer (score 5):

You may use `Application::hasDebugModeEnabled()` as an abstraction around the hardcoded config key.

Since Laravel 10, the method was also [added to the Application contract](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/46066).

Call it by either injecting the `Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application` contract into the constructor or by using the [app() helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-app).

Comment: You can also use the App facade with 
`App:hasDebugModeEnabled()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
env('APP_DEBUG') === false
```

to

```
env('APP_DEBUG') == false
```

Comment: this is not the right way, due to cache

Comment: Never use env outside the config files.

Answer (score -7):

In your .env file you should have:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```